# Emacs spell checking with hunspell: no spell-checking done

Tags: macos, emacs, spell-checking, hunspell, ispell

I would like to activate spell checking within GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (on Mac OS X 11.10). I did the following:

```
1) brew install hunspell
2) cd ~/Library/Spelling
   wget http://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/dictionaries/plain/en/en_US.aff
   wget http://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/dictionaries/plain/en/en_US.dic
```

(`hunspell -D` runs correctly from the terminal). In `~/.bash_profile` I set `export DICTIONARY=en_US` and my `~/.emacs` shows:

```
;; Activate Hunspell
(when (executable-find "hunspell")
  (setq-default ispell-program-name "/usr/local/bin/hunspell")
  (setq ispell-really-hunspell t))

;; Activate flyspell
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)
(add-hook 'message-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)
(setq flyspell-issue-message-flag nil)
(mapcar (lambda (mode-hook) (add-hook mode-hook 'flyspell-prog-mode))
    '(c-mode-common-hook R-mode-hook emacs-lisp-mode-hook))
```

However, when I open any `.txt` file, I don't see spell-checking errors underlined or anything... and `M-x ispell` shows `ispell-parse-hunspell-affix-file: ispell-phaf: No matching entry for nil.`. How can I get this to work?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25415070/hunspell-emacs-on-os-x-10-9) and [this](https://joelkuiper.eu/spellcheck_emacs) and [this](http://www.lonecpluspluscoder.com/2015/03/setting-up-emacs-spell-checking-on-os-x/) related post, but still couldn't figure out the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out: Setting the environment variable `DICTIONARY` in `~/.bash_profile` didn't work, but putting `(setenv "DICTIONARY" "en_US")` in `.emacs` solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I used this to conditionally load `hunspell` if `flyspell` can be loaded via `use-package` using `en_GB` dictionary.

Terminal commands:

```
brew install hunspell
cd ~/Library/Spelling/
wget http://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/dictionaries/plain/en/en_GB.aff
wget http://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/dictionaries/plain/en/en_GB.dic
ln -s en_GB.dic english.dic
ln -s en_GB.aff english.aff
```

Then in my Emacs init script:

```
  (use-package flyspell
    :hook ((text-mode . flyspell-mode)
           (prog-mode . flyspell-prog-mode))
    :config
    (when (executable-find "hunspell")
      (setq ispell-program-name (executable-find "hunspell"))
      (setq ispell-really-hunspell t)
      (setenv "DICTIONARY" "english"))
    (setq ispell-dictionary "english"))
```

Comment: Almost two years later! Do you know how I would use different languages in the setup you showed here? Thanks a lot

Comment: Yeah just replace the language-codes path (en/en_GB) and language names (english) to what you like. You can see the full index here: https://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/dictionaries/plain/